# I want the program to print all the possible combination

Tags: python, string, integer, combinations

I want the program in Python to print all the possible combinations of a number or characters of a string.

For example:

```
123
213
231
132
321
312
```

The amount is !3, but I'm not sure how to approach it.
I thought of using recursion, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.permutations` can do this for you.

```
import itertools
for c in itertools.permutations('123'):
    print(''.join(c))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you'd rather not [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720861/i-want-the-program-to-print-all-the-possible-combination/72720892#72720892) the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library you can use the code [from GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/):

```
def printCombination(arr, n, r):
    data = [0]*r;
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0,
                    n - 1, 0, r);

def combinationUtil(arr, data, start,
                    end, index, r):
    if (index == r):
        for j in range(r):
            print(data[j], end = " ");
        print();
        return;

    i = start;
    while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= r - index):
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1,
                        end, index + 1, r);
        i += 1;

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
r = 3;
n = len(arr);
printCombination(arr, n, r);
```

Answer (score -1):

We assume

```
X="123"
```

We want to find all the possible combinations.

```
import itertools
for c in itertools.permutations(X) :
print(''.join(c))
```

Comment: Where did you copy that from? It doesn't even compile: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`